# Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration with Non-administrative user (Access Denied)

Tags: networking, wmi

I'm trying the change some configurations of the network adapters locally. I have to use a non-administrative user, but I just get the return value "91", which stands for "Access Denied", when I try to invoke methods. It was possible to set the rights for the "EnableStatic" method, but "SetDNSServerSearchOrder" doesn't work at all. It always returns "Access Denied". I cannot even disable the network adapter (in Win32_NetworkAdapter). Everything works great with an admin user. Since I had the same problem with "EnableStatic", I'm pretty sure, that there must be a way to get this working with the other methods. I set the security options in wmimgmt.msc for all namespaces, I set the limits in dcomcnfg, I granted permissions in the registry for tcpip, added the user in distributed com-users, performance groups, network configuration operators, but there is no way to get this working. I recognized, that there is no dns ip, when my tool was running. So something changes although the method is returning "Access Denied". Any ideas? Even Microsoft couldn't help me yet, since three weeks now. The tool is running without any problems, when I'm logged in as admin. Here is my C# Code: (and sorry for some mistakes in my written English ;) )

```
    private static ManagementScope CreateScope(string strScope)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(strScope);
        scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        scope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
        return scope;
    }

    public static void SetIP(String strScope, String strQuery, string IPAddress, string SubnetMask, string Gateway, string DNSServer1, string DNSServer2)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = CreateScope(strScope);
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(strQuery);
        Collection<object> objCol = new Collection<object>();
        scope.Connect();
        ManagementObjectCollection mobjCol = null;
        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
        {
            mobjCol = searcher.Get();
        }
        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in mobjCol)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject objNewIP = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objSetIP = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objNewGate = null;
                ManagementBaseObject objNewDNS = null;

                objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                objNewDNS = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");

                //Set DefaultGateway
                objNewGate["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { Gateway };
                objNewGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                //Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
                objNewIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { IPAddress };
                objNewIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { SubnetMask };

                //Set DNS servers
                objNewDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = new string[] { DNSServer1, DNSServer2 };

                //Invoke all changes
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, null);
                MessageBox.Show("EnableStatic: " + objSetIP["ReturnValue"].ToString());
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, null);
                MessageBox.Show("SetGateways: " + objSetIP["ReturnValue"].ToString());
                objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", objNewDNS,null);                                                               
                MessageBox.Show("SetDNSServerSearchOrder: " + objSetIP["ReturnValue"].ToString());


            }
            catch (ManagementException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to Set IP : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

non-administrative users need permissions to run WMI queries. You can set the relevant permissions using WMI Control [under ServerManager / Configuration or Computer Management / Services & Applications] ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775497(v=ws.10).aspx

Try providing Execute Methods, Enable Account & Provider Write permissions to your non-admin user in the CIMV2 namespace.